# ¿Cómo hacer una gráfica lineal en c# windows form?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

¿Es posible hacer una gráfica en c# como [este](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/yaxis/opposite/)?

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        marginRight: 80 // like left
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    yAxis: [{
        lineWidth: 1,
        title: {
            text: 'Primary Axis'
        }
    }, {
        lineWidth: 1,
        opposite: true,
        title: {
            text: 'Secondary Axis'
        }
    }],

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }, {
        data: [144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2],
        yAxis: 1
    }]
});
```

```html
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
```

Estoy usando un chart pero esta lejos de parecerse. La gráfica del ejemplo, está hecha en `JavaScript` pero quisiera uno para poder visualizarlo en un windows form.

Comment: Hola Zenaido. Muestranos ese chart que has intentado para ver por que está lejos de parecerse. Un saludo

Comment: Para hacer formularios con graficos y demas te recomiendo que investiges como hacerlo en WPF, en concreto con XAML que es la herramienta que ofrece .NET

Comment: Consulta este ejemplo el cual usa: [Chart Control](http://csharpexamples.com/c-chart-control-example/).

Comment: He encontrado esta herramienta https://lvcharts.net/

Answer (score 1):

Usando el control incluido en .net, lo arrastras hacia el formulario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Despues haces lo siguiente:

Generamos la clase que contendra los puntos a graficar, esta clase contiene el mes (eje x de la grafica) y las series a graficar (los puntos que se representan en cada mes):

```
public class Series
    {
        public string mes { get; set; }
        public decimal Serie1 { get; set; }
        public decimal Serie2 { get; set; }
    }
```

Los graficos del control chart requieren el uso de IEnumerable, el caul esta incluido en el tipo List, asi que generamos una lista de nuestra clase y aqui yo inicializo los valores de las dos series manualmente, pero igual los puedes generar destu una base de datos o un archivo.

Despues en donde inicialices el grafico (La inicializacion puede ser en un metodo, en el constructor del formulario o en el evento load del formulario):

```
List<Series> datosSeries = new List<Series>
        {
            new Series
            {
                mes = "JAN",
                Serie1 = 29.9m,
                Serie2 = 144.0m
            },
            new Series
            {
                mes = "FEB",
                Serie1 = 71.5m,
                Serie2 = 176.0m
            },
            new Series
            {
                mes = "MAR",
                Serie1 = 106.4m,
                Serie2 = 135.6m
            },
            new Series
            {
                mes = "APR",
                Serie1 = 129.2m,
                Serie2 = 148.5m
            },
            new Series
            {
                mes = "MAY",
                Serie1 = 144.0m,
                Serie2 = 216.4m
            },
            new Series
            {
                mes = "JUN",
                Serie1 = 176.0m,
                Serie2 = 194.1m
            },
        };
        chart1.Series.Clear();  //Eliminamos cualquier serie del grafico
        chart1.DataBindTable(datosSeries, "mes"); //Enlazamos nuestra lista al grafico y le indicamos la propiedad que se usara para el eje X
        chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line; //Tipo de grafico de linea para la serie 1
        chart1.Series[1].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line; //Tipo de grafico de linea para la serie 2
```

Lo cual te dara un resultado como: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cuál es el control que va incluido en .Net para hacer las gráficas? Si pudieras poner más detalles al respecto me parece que tu respuesta puede ser la indicada para solucionar el problema del OP :)

Comment: Edite de acuerdo a lo solicitado. saludos

Answer (score 0):

Poder se pude lograr, el tema es que los componentes que usarias no son gratuitos

[DevExpress Stacked Line Chart](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument9977)

[telerik RadChartView](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms/chartview.aspx)

Estos componentes permiten las graficas que buscas en winforms, pero como mencione son componentes pagos.