# ¿Cómo hacer una gráfica lineal en c# windows form sin usar Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono

Buenas tardes.

Estoy programando C# en Xamarin Studio, y quiero crear una gráfica de líneas sin emplear Visual Studio.

Vi este ejemplo sencillo

> [¿Cómo hacer una gráfica lineal en c# windows form?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/48293/c%c3%b3mo-hacer-una-gr%c3%a1fica-lineal-en-c-windows-form)

Pero al probar y ejecutar no me ha visualizado. Se agradece cualquier solución. Muchas gracias.

Comment: que quiere decir sin visual studio? visual studio es el entorno de programación...

Comment: Buenas tardes, gbianchi. Estoy usando Xamarin Studio para C#, y me ha tocado hacer una gráfica de líneas. Pero no puedo emplear el entorno de Visual Studio, ya que no dispongo de una Vista Diseño y tengo que codificar desde cero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estás utilizando la [implementación de **Windows Forms** en Mono](http://www.go-mono.com/status/status.aspx?reference=4.0&profile=4.0&assembly=System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization). **WinForms** fue abandonada por Xamarin antes de estar terminada. Aunque no indicas el error que te da, el problema será seguramente la excepción **NotImplementedException**.

Tienes dos alternativas.

1. Utilizar un ensamblado externo, como por ejemplo el proyecto [ZedGraph](https://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/).
2. Dibujar el gráfico tú mismo. Puedes tomar como ejemplo el código [DemoWinForms en Github](https://github.com/baltasarq/WinFormsDemo) (nota: es mío), que encontrarás en la clase **Chart**.